# Get clicked li id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested-sortable

I have the following list:

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable">
    <li id="list_1608"><div>One</div></li>
    <li id="list_1609"><div>Two</div></li>
    <li id="list_1610"><div>Three</div></li>
</ol>
```

I want to get the `id` of any `li` that is clicked. I have tried the following code but get no alert.

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var myid = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(myid);
});
```

I am using this in conjunction with the nestedSortable jQuery Plugin.

Where am I going wrong?

**Ok Further info, the list items are added after the dom is loaded.**

If the items are loaded to start with it does work, apologies.

Comment: as normal it is working....please provide us the whole code..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/MqEDF/), you may need to put it in `document.ready()` or need to [**add jQuery files**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery). Using `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")` is better option here as it is javascript and gives you performance benefit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("li").click(function() {
        //var myid = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(this.id);
     });

})
```

Comment: @Adil you can make this more efficient with just `var myid = this.id;` but +1 nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id with:

```
this.id
```

Comment: That's not the problem here so this should be a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
$('ol').click(function(event){
if(event.target.tagName == 'li'){alert(this.id);}
if($(event.target).parent('li').length > 0){$(this).parent().attr('id');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have loaded the jquery library properly first within `head` tag

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $("li").click(function() {
        var myid = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(myid);
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference. Although the above answer was correct for static data I forgot to mention that the elements were added after the DOM had loaded. The solution was in fact..

```
$("li").live("click", function({
    alert(this.id);
 });
```